# LINQ to SQL Insert

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

i'm using LINQ To SQL to perform an insert via db.table.InsertOnSubmit(). I'm wondering if there is a way to reproduce the T-SQL version of the 'where not exists (select etc etc) begin insert into etc etc end' as one single query? Thanks, Martin

Comment: Perhaps a more rounded description of your T-SQL (like an actual chunk of T-SQL code) would also make this question better

Comment: Explaining which is the task you are trying to accomplish, might gave you better responses.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ has an extension method called Contains which allows for this functionality. This can be seen in the following example:

```
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
dc.Log = Console.Out;
var query =
    from c in dc.Customers
    where !(from o in dc.Orders
            select o.CustomerID)
           .Contains(c.CustomerID)
    select c;
foreach (var c in query) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Note the negation on the where clause!

This example was from the website [here](http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Nothing build in as far as I know, we would have to go about finding the row manually using where and than do the Insert.

There is a possibility of race coditions in such queries. Have a look at this thread for detailed solution :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/b1a0eb5b-d5d3-41af-829f-bbbac47b7383/